# javafx custom layout pane: label always returns -1 for its preferred width and height

Tags: java, layout, javafx

I try to implement a custom layout pane in javafx which will position all nodes in a circle around its center.
The Problem is that my Nodes always return -1.0 for their preferredwidth and minwidth and height properties. Here is my class:

```
public class CirclePane extends Region {

@Override
protected void layoutChildren() {
    double middleX = getWidth() / 2;
    double middleY = getHeight() / 2;
    double factor = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 0.45;// how far from the middle the nodes will be arranged
    double degreesPerChild = 2 * Math.PI / getChildren().size();
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildren().size(); i++) {
        if(getChildren().get(i) instanceof Region){
            Region r = (Region) getChildren().get(i); // I believe I need region to get any sizes?
            double prefW = Math.max(r.getMinWidth(), r.getPrefWidth()); //My attempt to get a reliable preferredwidth and height
            double prefH = Math.max(r.getMinHeight(), r.getPrefHeight());

            double degrees = i * degreesPerChild;
            double xPos = Math.sin(degrees) * factor + middleX - prefW / 2;
            double yPos = Math.cos(degrees) * factor + middleY - prefH / 2;
            layoutInArea(r, xPos , yPos, prefW, prefH, 0.0d, HPos.LEFT, VPos.CENTER);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public ObservableList<Node> getChildren() {
    return super.getChildren();
}
```

It works, but all Nodes are moved to the right (a few pixels, approximately their width / 2).
Also, I want to make sure other components fit correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself.
To get the right width and height, you have to call [`Region.prefWidth(-1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#prefWidth-double-) and [`Region.prefHeight(-1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#prefHeight-double-)respectively.

The purpose of these two functions is to be:

> Called during layout to determine the preferred width/height for this node.

Comment: that is what I'm doing, isn't it? I made a custom layout pane which uses these methods to get the preferred width / height for this node??